# Gap in the bottom of a page on mobile device in portrait mode

Tags: css, android-layout, mobile

When I browse my website on computer, everything looks fine in all major browsers, however, when I check it on Android phone there's a massive gap below footer. This happens **only in portrait mode** and in all android browsers. When I view it in landscape mode, the gap disappears in all browsers.

I tried 'playing' with viewport meta tag, but it doesn't help.

My site's width: 1300px and height:100%. Also, footer has padding-bottom:0; margin-bottom:0;

What could cause this problem to happen only in portrait mode?

Update: It seems that the height of a page isn't large enough to fill entire screen of my mobile so there's this gap. When I browse the page it's completely zoomed out according to sites width. How to make it zoom in according to site's height instead and thereby eliminate the bottom gap?

Please help

P.S. Unfortunately, I cannot provide you link to the site as it's on a local server.

Comment: What happens if you remove the height:100%?

Comment: Tried it couple seconds ago and no changes.

Comment: try position absolute and bottom 0

Comment: "I cannot provide you link to the site as it's on a local server." Yes but you can still reduce it to a simple example which shows the same behaviour and put that onto JSFiddle...

Comment: Abdul Malik, tried it and nothing changed. Ambrose, I'm not sure how to replicate this problem on JSFiddle.

The problem doesn't exist when viewed in landscape mode. It seems that page isn't high enough to fill mobile's screen vertically, hence there's white space in the bottom. Ideally, it should just zoom in until mobile's screen is full vertically. I tried it with viewport, but gap is still there. 

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, guys. I managed to fix it. Probably not the best fix in the world but better than nothing.
So what I did was forced minimum zoom by using viewport minimum-scale=0.6.

No bottom gap after this fix.